# Can I use a certificate package with an ESP8266 and the RTOS SDK?

Tags: esp8266

I'm connecting an ESP8266 to an MQTT broker but the broker will be changing their certificates shortly.  I am trying to avoid having to re-flash my devices with this happens but how can I place both the current and new certificates on my device and have the ESP8266 se them?

It appears that the newer ESP-IDF SDK (which I don't believe supports) allows a certificate package to be defined that is used but the ESP8266-RTOS-SDK does not appear to have this function.  Is there a way to either enable or emulate this function?

Comment: I cannot give you _specific_ advice but in general you don't want to embed the actual soon-to-expire certificate but the CA root certificate instead: [cert]<-[intermediate cert]<-[CA cert].

Comment: Thanks Marcel - it's the Root certificate which is being changed if I understand this link, https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/azure-iot-tls-critical-changes-are-almost-here-and-why-you/ba-p/2393169, correctly.

Comment: Oh bummer, an IoT cloud like Azure changing their CA is always going to cause a lot of pain for many (if the device firmware does not support OTA). I usually work with the Arduino abstraction on ESP8266 and ESP32 instead of RTOS. `BearSSL::X509List` allows to define a set of CA certs to build your own pseudo SSL package. See e.g. https://www.dzombak.com/blog/2021/10/HTTPS-Requests-with-a-Small-Set-of-Root-Certificates-on-ESP8266-Arduino.html.

Comment: Thanks - I think it is possible to switch to using BearSSL in the RTOS framework.  Might be worth me doing that providing there are no other changes although I'm actually using some of the TLS functions to generate the Azure SAS token (requires HMAC() and similar algorithms).